# Python - searching in Google and collecting title and description

Tags: python, pandas, search, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I need to search in Google a few words from a CSV file, and to collect from the google search - URL, google description and title.

I managed to write a script to search the words, collect only the URLs and store the results in a CSV file. I can't figure out how to collect - Title and google description. Also, I need to return - "missing results" if the word I search is not found.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from googlesearch import search
import pandas as pd

keywords = pd.read_csv('keywords.csv', header=0, index_col=None)

#print(keywords['keyword'])

df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['keyword', 'url'])

for i in keywords['keyword']:
    print('Search results for keyword: ', i)
    count = 0
    for j in search(i, tld="co.in", num=10, stop=3, pause=2, lang='en'):
        count = count + 1
        print('URL number ',count, ': ', j)
        df = df.append({'keyword': i, 'url': j}, ignore_index=True)

df.to_csv(r'final_dataset.csv', index=False)
```

Comment: You'll need to provide more information about `search(i, tld="co.in", num=10, stop=3, pause=2, lang='en')`.

Comment: @JackFleeting that's not all, google mechanize became more harder. and whatever you will do. it's will catch the ip and block it. using serpapi or  zenserp is good solution as for now.

Answer (score 0):

- specify `user-agent` in order not to be blocked by Google while making a request. [What is my user-agent?](https://www.whatismybrowser.com/detect/what-is-my-user-agent)
- try [SelectorGadget](https://selectorgadget.com/) Chrome extension to visually grab `CSS` selectors by clicking on the desired element.

Code and [full example in the online IDE](https://replit.com/@DimitryZub1/Scrape-Google-from-CSV-keywords-Title-Snippet-Link#main.py) (note: the following code is **not** appending to `.csv`, instead it will overwrite existing file):

```py
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests, lxml

headers = {
    'User-agent':
    "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/70.0.3538.102 Safari/537.36 Edge/18.19582"
}

keywords = pd.read_csv('keywords.csv', header=0, index_col=None)

# collected data
data = []

for query in keywords['keywords']:
  html = requests.get(f'https://www.google.com/search?q={query}', headers=headers)
  soup = BeautifulSoup(html.text, 'lxml')

  for result in soup.select('.tF2Cxc'):
    title = result.select_one('.DKV0Md').text
    link = result.select_one('.yuRUbf a')['href']
    displayed_link = result.select_one('.TbwUpd.NJjxre').text

    try:
      snippet = result.select_one('#rso .lyLwlc').text
    except: snippet = None

    print(f'{title}\n{link}\n{displayed_link}\n{snippet}\n')

    # appending all data to array as dict()
    data.append({
      'title': title,
      'link': link,
      'displayed link': displayed_link,
      'snippet': snippet
    })

  # create dataframe and save it as .csv
  df = pd.DataFrame(data)
  df.to_csv('bs4_final.csv', index=False)
```

Alternatively, you can do it as well by using [Google Organic Results API](https://serpapi.com/organic-results) from SerpAPI as [αԋɱҽԃ αмєяιcαη](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59451872/python-searching-in-google-and-collecting-title-and-description#comment105091515_59451872) mentioned in the comments. It's a paid API with a free plan.

The main difference is that you only need to iterate over JSON string without doing any additional things.

Code to integrate:

```py
from serpapi import GoogleSearch
import os
import pandas as pd

keywords = pd.read_csv('keywords.csv', header=0, index_col=None)

for query in keywords['keywords']:
    params = {
      "api_key": os.getenv("API_KEY"),
      "engine": "google",
      "q": query,
      "hl": "en",
    }

    search = GoogleSearch(params)
    results = search.get_dict()

    data = []

    for result in results['organic_results']:
        title = result['title']
        link = result['link']
        displayed_link = result['displayed_link']
        snippet = result['snippet']
                
        print(f"{title}\n{link}\n{displayed_link}\n{snippet}\n")

        data.append({
          'title': title,
          'link': link,
          'displayed link': displayed_link,
          'snippet': snippet
        })

    df = pd.DataFrame(data)
    df.to_csv('serpapi_final.csv', index=False)
```

P.S - I wrote a [blog post](https://dev.to/dimitryzub/scrape-google-organic-search-with-python-3hp5) with visuals (*gifs*) about how to scrape Google Organic Search results.

> Disclaimer, I work for SerpApi.